# New-AzPolicyAssignment - Paramter is not being assigned

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-policy

I am trying to assign a built-in policy to scope through PowerShell, **it is being assigned however the parameter is not being added to the assignment.**
In Particular, "**Deploy Log Analytics agent for Linux VMs**", is being assigned correctly but upon checking assignment, the policy is correctly assigned but parameter "logAnalytics" is empty however we already have a LogAnalytics workspace.

```
Connect-AzAccount 
$subscriptionID ='ABCDFGG-ADSFSDF--SFSDF'
get-azsubscription -SubscriptionId  $subscriptionID| set-azcontext 

$PolicyName = 'Deploy Log Analytics agent for Linux VMs'
$NewName = 'Deploy Log Analytics agent for Linux VMs-Aug04-2'

# Get a reference to the policy definition to assign
$PolicyAssign = Get-AzPolicyDefinition  | Where-Object { $_.Properties.DisplayName -eq $PolicyName} 
$Paramter = @{'logAnalytics'=('LA-TEST-EU1')}

New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name $NewName -DisplayName $NewName  -Scope /subscriptions/$($SubscriptionId) -PolicyDefinition $PolicyAssign  -PolicyParameterObject $Paramter -Location 'eastUS' -AssignIdentity
```

Comment: I just now checked below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logAnalytics parameter value should be in the format of the Resource ID:

> /subscriptions/[SUBSCRIPTIION-ID]/resourcegroups/[RESOURCEGROUP-NAME]/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/[WORKSPACENAME]

If you go to your Log Analytics Workspace > Properties you will find the Resource ID. That ID is what you need to use.

Comment: @SKumar what i provided was an example but anyway i did some clarification now.